# Should else & else-if statements be on separate lines

Tags: java, coding-style

Which one of these styles is more widely used and appropriate?

1.

```
    if (condition1) {
        //...
    } else if (condition2) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
```

2.

```
    if (condition1) {
        //...
    }
    else if (condition2) {
        //...
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Whichever makes you feel all fluffy inside is the best one. [Google says first option](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.6.2-horizontal-whitespace), [Oracle says first option](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449).

Comment: neither. I try to use switch whenever possible instead of multiple if-else.

Comment: Or you can try to drop both altogether: http://antiifcampaign.com

Comment: I edit your examples a little to make it more general (hope that  `if(true)`, `if(false)` or `return;` wasn't very important in your question).

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will go with `1` with one change:

```
if (condition1) {
    //...
} else if (condition2) {
    //...
} 
return;
```

I'm using this solution because I have few lines of code. For example there are code styles which are not allowing more then `N` lines of code in methods.